# Using minimum description length for a categorical distribution

Tags: categorical-data, model-selection, multinomial-distribution, information-criteria

My data is as follows: in a routing node (check [figure](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5363697/Mdl/Note%20Jul%2030%2C%202012.pdf) ), I can see the entry and exit gate of each packet, so I have pairs like this:

```
(1,5) (2,5) (1,6) ...
```

where the first number of each pair represents the entry gate and the second number represents the exit gate. I want to note, that in general, an entry gate can also be an exit gate.

Now, I want to test different models for the relationship between entry and exit gates that packets use. For example, one model could be that the exit gates are independent of the entry gates, even if each exit gate has a fixed probability. In this case, the exit gate follows a categorical probability distribution, and the number of times that each exit gate is used when N packets are considered, follows a multinomial distribution. The distributions have as parameters the probability of taking each individual exit gate.In more elaborated models, I  take into account the entry gate of the packet, for example, by saying that the probability of using the entry gate also as exit is, either very low, or very high, and only after that the other gates present at the node are used.

I have constructed several of these models, and well enough, most of them use a categorical distribution of some sort, which ends up being a multinomial distribution when considering multiple packets . For discriminating between the models, I want to use Minimum Description Length. So far I have used the rather simplistic [BIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion). However, as many authors note, BIC can be misleading for short data-samples. So, I want to employ at least the refinement that uses Fisher Information Matrix:

Model complexity/given-data =
$$
-\ln f(x\mid \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}_x}) + \frac{k}{2}\ln \left(\frac{n}{2\pi}\right)+\ln \int_{\theta} \sqrt{\det I(\boldsymbol{\theta})} d\boldsymbol{\theta} + o(1)
$$

where $n$ denotes the sample size, $k$ is the number of model parameters, and $I(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is the Fisher information matrix *of sample size 1* defined as:

$$
I(\boldsymbol{\theta})_{i,j}=-E_{f(\cdot\mid\theta)}\left[\frac{\partial^2 \ln f(x\mid \boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j}\right]
$$

Here my troubles begin. First

1. What exactly "*sample size 1*" conveys? Does it mean that I should consider the probability distribution of just 1 sample, which in my case would be the categorical distribution?
2. If I'm right in 1, then, can I take derivatives with respect to my model parameters, i.e., the probabilities of the categories?

I can also use general recommendations, as unfortunately I know far too little about statistics.